# What is meaning of square of inverse of a matrix A?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Suppose we have a **n** by **n** square matrix **A**, which consists of **n** linearly independent column vectors $\in$ $ R^n $ , therefore vectors span $ R^n $, which implies that matrix is invertible and transformation is one-to-one.

I was thinking that it is possible to find linear combination of column vectors which gives inverse of $A$ = $A^{-1}$. Before solving for all columns, let's take example for one column of $A^{-1}$ so we set up equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$

where $\vec{x}$ is unknown

$\vec{b}$ is a column of $A^{-1}$.

As matrix $A$ and $A^{-1}$ is known, one can solve above mentioned equation:

$A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ therefore  $A^{-1} A\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$ therefore $I\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$ therefore
$\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$

Recall, that $\vec{b}$ itself was a column of $A^{-1}$

If one want to solve for all columns, matrix equations follows like this:

$A*B=A^{-1}$

where $B$ is matrix with coefficients which multiplied by $A$ gives $A^{-1}$

So I come with this equation:

$AB=A^{-1}$ therefore  $A^{-1} AB=A^{-1}A^{-1}$ therefore $IB=A^1A^{-1}$ therefore
$B=A^{-1}A^{-1}$

So, is it correct to conclude that inverse of a matrix $A$ squared gives a **n** by **n** matrix $B$ which multiplied by $AB$ = $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Let $A$ be an invertible matrix and $B=A^{-1}$. Then the square of the inverse of $A$ is $B^2=A^{-2}$. So multiplying this by $A$ yields $AB^2=A^{-1}$.

Comment: $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ is the defining property of the inverse of $A$. To find it set up the matrix $[A \vert I]$ and use gaussian elimination to get the form $[I \vert B]$ and you'll have $B = A^{-1}$.

Comment: $AA^{-2}=A^{-1}$, just as for numbers $aa^{-2}=a^{-1}$ (provided all terms are defined).